# How do I implement customer personalization using Facebook OpenGraph?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, personalization

I'm currently integrating the OpenGraph into a restaurant business. The code/scripts provided seem to work fine in a staging environment, however I want to go one step further: when a person visits the site, and they're logged in to Facebook, I would like to display a specific message for them.

Let's say their name it Steven Smith, I would like to add a section at the top of the site which says "Welcome Steven, what would you like to do?", with three options provided with links to relevant pages.

Is this something that I will need to write a script for? Or is it something that I have missed with the tools available?

Answer (score 0):

This is called 'instant personalization' and is only available to a select few Facebook partners.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to setup an app, have the user authenticate to your app, and then when the user comes to the page and you call `FB.getLoginStatus()` to see if they're already connected to your app.  If so, you know who they are and can display their name.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {      
    if (response.status=='connected') {
        FB.api('/me',function(response){
            alert('Welcome back ' + response.name);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As your spec says, this covers exactly what you want to achieve:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

You need fb app to auth, after auth, get the permission for reading only (minimal one which can't post or like),

then,

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     DisplayFunc('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       DisplayFunc('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     DisplayFunc('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```